# PHP: Create Image Box whose Height Depends on its Contained Text

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I am trying to use **PHP** to create an image of a transparent text box with max. 2 lines of text. The box width is fixed at 90px; the height varies depending on the contained text (again, the text might occupy 1 to 2 lines): [example](http://savvy.siku-siku.com/lab/image-merge/create-text.png).

I think the most challenging part is how to "automatically" set the box height depending on the text length. That is, the script should be intelligent enough to:

1. Wrap the text (to a 2nd line) if it's longer than the width.
2. Adjust the box height because now there are two lines.

Assuming the text always fits one line and the box, the script can be rather simple:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(90, 22);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 92, 149, 167);

// Set the background to be blue
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 90, 22, $blue);

// Path to our font file
$font = './Arial.ttf';

imagefttext($im, 10, 0, 5, 15, $white, $font, "Barton Hotel");

// Output to browser
header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [imagettfbox](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) to get the bounding box of text and use that information to actually generate the box.

I have this function to generate word image:

```
function generate_words($word)
{
    $fontSize = 10;
    $fontFile = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/fonts/verdana.ttf';
    $boundingBox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $fontFile, $word);
    $imageWord = imagecreate(abs($boundingBox[2]) + abs($boundingBox[0]), abs($boundingBox[7]) + abs($boundingBox[1]));
    $background = imagecolorallocate($imageWord, 255, 255, 255);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($imageWord, 0, 0, 0);
    imagettftext($imageWord, $fontSize, 0, 0, abs($boundingBox[5]), $black, $fontFile, $word);
    //print_r( $boundingBox );

    return $imageWord;    
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$imageWord = generate_words( "my text" );
$imageWordWidth = imagesx($imageWord);
$imageWordHeight = imagesy($imageWord);
```

and finally, combine resulting text image resource into base or background image:

```
imagecopymerge($baseImage, $imageWord, $wordXLocationRelativeToBase, $wordYLocationRelativeToBase, 0, 0, $imageWordWidth, $imageWordHeight, 100);
```

Comment: Maybe I was lacking an understanding what the bounding box is for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8587301/583539. Help?